# Blockage in bendy pipe

Tags: plumbing, drain, pipe, drainage, blockage

I have a problematic pipe that has a blockage.  Problematic for three reasons:

1. I could not snake through it (I have a 25 feet snake with a manual spin, spent a good while spinning trying to snake through, could not :(
2. it builds up blockage very quickly (2 months) - now can have only about 5% water in shower than usual to avoid flooding
3. no clean out cap/access point around the bendy area (red circle)

[image]

Can someone please suggest:

a) short term/quick fixes I can do?

b) solutions (expensive/inexpensive) that a plumber may be able to do?

Note that there's not much of a drop from shower drain level to the soil pipe level (because of the storage door and where soil pipe is located).  See below.

[image]

Note also that the pipe is all glued up. Can't disconnect anywhere in order to take out the blockage.

Very many thanks for any comments/answers,

Ben

Comment: Not sure what the fix is, but a snake won't pass through a 90 degree fitting.  Normally "sweeps" are used rather than sharp 90's to help water flow and consequentially allow snakes to navigate.  What city/country is this in?

Comment: @JPhi1618 Ah, sweep, that was what I was thinking. A smooth path rather than with many sharp corners.

Comment: This is in London, UK.

Comment: Just curious because I've not seen drains on the outside of a wall, or 90's used in drain pipe...  Does liquid drain cleaner help at all since the mechanical snake can't get through?  Maybe a weekly regimen of some drain cleaner after the shower is in order?

Comment: I see lots of outdoor piping here in London. What's the best liquid drain cleaner brand do you find?

Comment: Michael's answer is what I was getting at.  This is kind of devolving into a chat, and I don't even know what brand of drain openers the sell in the UK.  replacing the 90's with sweeps and adding some Y-type cleanouts shouldn't be a big deal for you or a plumber to do.

Comment: just an aside...I *love* the idea of outside plumbing. Why hide this stuff in walls? Make it accessible!

Comment: @DA01 Unless you live in a cold climate, then it could be quite troublesome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd suggest the following (apologies for the crude drawing).

From left-to-right:

- extend pipe out past the black pipe
- attach yellow clean-out elbow (not 90 degree!...use a sweep (yellow))
- this will be angled down aiming towards the run along the other wall
- connect the sweep to the other pipe using two 45 degree elbows (purple)

[image]

Sweep with cleanout:

[image]

45 degree elbow:

[image]

That should:

- remove any 90 degree turns (never a good thing in a drain)
- reduce turns in general (from 5 to 3)
- give you a 'snake-able' cleanout entry point.

While you're at it, I'd also move upstream to that inside corner 90 degree angle and replace that with a 90 degree sweep as well.

Comment: Brilliant. Very clever. That is almost what I had in mind, I thought that perhaps the hopper container could be removed as well (I believe it's unused - the water pipe originally went into the hooper until we replaced it with the pipe that you see). Really like your diagram. Thanks :)

Comment: I agree, there are too many directional changes in this plumbing.  The plumber went with form over function, which might be a side effect of visible plumbing. Where gravity drains are concerned, less turns and wider turns are always better.

Answer (score 4):

Glued up PVC pipe should not be any sort of detriment to getting inside to remove a clog. Just cut open a section, clean and then install new fittings to rejoin the line. While you are at it replace some of those horrible 90 degree elbows with a better type of couplings that will not clog so easily as a bunch of these sharp turn elbows. Also take the time to add some access points with screw thread caps to permit the introduction of a clean-out tool in the future.

From the pictures shown this plumbing job looks like it was a total hack job.

Comment: For reference, this is a [Y-type cleanout](http://extension.missouri.edu/explore/images/wq0402art4b.jpg) that could be added, and [this](http://terrylove.com/forums/index.php?attachments/bathroom_rough5close-jpg.22363/) is an example of sweeping curves that are used rather than hard 90s (no idea if that plumbing job is good form, just look at the curved pieces...)

Comment: In terms of mechanics, I agree totally...total hack job. That said, we gotta give them a few points for aesthetics. :)